# mapeo de propiedades observables que funciona en stackblitz pero en local no

Tags: angular, observable

En este proyecto: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-byvfjy?file=src/app/avales/filtro-avales/filtro-avales.component.ts

En el componente filtro-avales.component.ts

mapeo una serie de propiedades en función de lo que encuentro en una serie de observables previamente obtenidos

```
 avalesConPropiedadesMapeadas$ = forkJoin([
  this.avales$,
  this.tipoAvales$,
  this.estadoAvales$,
  this.avalistas$,
  this.responsables$,
  this.proyectos$,
  this.oferta$

])
.pipe(
  map(([avales, tipoAvales, estadoAvales, avalistas, responsables, proyectos, ofertas]) =>
    avales.map(aval => ({
      ...aval,
      tipoAval: tipoAvales.find(t => t.id == aval.tipoAvalId),
      estadoAval: estadoAvales.find(t => t.id == aval.estadoAvalId),
      avalista: avalistas.find(t => t.id == aval.avalistaId),
      responsableNombre: responsables.find(r => r.id == aval.responsableId).nombreCompleto,
      clienteId: proyectos.find(p => p.id == aval.proyectoId)?.clienteId,
      clienteNombre: proyectos.find(p => p.id == aval.proyectoId)?.clienteNombre,
      proyectoDescripcion: proyectos.find(p => p.id == aval.proyectoId)?.descripcion,
      ofertaDescripcion:ofertas.find(o=>o.id==aval.ofertaId)?.descripcion
    }) as Aval))
 );
```

Esto mismo cuando lo intento hacer en mi proyecto en local VS Code me marca estos errores al compilar

[image: errores]

No entiendo la razón y no se si está relacionado con las versiones de Typescript u otras

Alguna idea, por favor?

Salu2

Comment: Que versión de angular usas? y al posicionar el mouse en cualquiera de los find que te señala en rojo que mensaje te sale?

Comment: @jGomez  @angular/core": "~13.1.2" y al poner el mouse en cualquiera de los find me dice: No se puede llamar a esta expresión.
  Cada miembro del tipo de unión "{ <S extends Proyecto>(predicate: (this: void, value: Proyecto, index: number, obj: Proyecto[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any): S; (predicate: (value: Proyecto, index: number, obj: Proyecto[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any): Proyecto; } | { ...; } | { ...; } | { ...; }" tiene signaturas, pero ninguna de ellas es compatible entre sí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validando lo que posees, puede que el error que presentas es porque en el angular, los parametros que tienes los está tratando como parámetros de tipo any, puedes probar hacer lo siguiente.

```
avalesConPropiedadesMapeadas$ = forkJoin([
  this.avales$,
  this.tipoAvales$,
  this.estadoAvales$,
  this.avalistas$,
  this.responsables$,
  this.proyectos$,
  this.oferta$
])
.pipe(
  map(([avales, tipoAvales, estadoAvales, avalistas, responsables, 
    proyectos, ofertas]) =>
    avales.map(aval => ({
    ...aval,
      tipoAval: (tipoAvales as TipoAval[]).find(t => t.id == aval.tipoAvalId),
      estadoAval: (estadoAvales as EstadoAval[]).find(t => t.id == aval.estadoAvalId),
      avalista: (avalistas as Avalista[]).find(t => t.id == aval.avalistaId),
      responsableNombre: (responsables as Responsable[]).find(r => r.id == aval.responsableId).nombreCompleto,
      clienteId: (proyectos as Proyecto[]).find(p => p.id == aval.proyectoId)?.clienteId,
      clienteNombre: (proyectos as Proyecto[]).find(p => p.id == aval.proyectoId)?.clienteNombre,
      proyectoDescripcion: (proyectos as Proyecto[]).find(p => p.id == aval.proyectoId)?.descripcion,
      ofertaDescripcion: (ofertas as Oferta[]).find(o=>o.id==aval.ofertaId)?.descripcion
    }) as Aval))
 );
```

Si esto no ste sirve, avisas para probar otra cosa,

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tiene su origen en la **Union de tipos** invocables   para diferentes tipos de array  Aunque en mi proyecto con typescript  4.3.5 la unica modificacion respecto al tuyo es si uso strict:true debo usar Non-null assertion operator tambien el uso de
as unknown cuando es intencionado

```js
let avalesConPropiedadesMapeadas$:
    Observable<(Aval | TipoAval | EstadoAval | Avalista | Responsable | Proyecto)[]>= forkJoin([
      of(avales),
      this.tipoAvales$,
      this.estadoAvales$,
      this.avalistas$,
      this.responsables$,
      this.proyectos$
    ])
      .pipe(
        map
        (
          (
            [avales, tipoAvales, estadoAvales, avalistas, responsables, proyectos]
          )  :(Aval|TipoAval |EstadoAval |Avalista |Responsable |Proyecto)[] =>
          avales.map(
            (aval:Aval) => ({
            ...aval,
            tipoAval: tipoAvales.find(t => t.id == aval.tipoAvalId)!.nombre,
            estadoAval: estadoAvales.find(t => t.id == aval.estadoAvalId)!.nombre,
            avalista: avalistas.find(t => t.id == aval.avalistaId)!.nombre,
            responsableNombre:responsables.find(r => r.id == aval.responsableId)!.nombreCompleto,
            clienteId:proyectos.find(p=>p.id==aval.proyectoId)?.clienteId,
            clienteNombre:proyectos.find(p=>p.id==aval.proyectoId)?.clienteNombre
          }) as unknown as Aval))
      );

      avalesConPropiedadesMapeadas$
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.dataSource= data as Aval[];
        }
        , err => console.log(err)
        , () => {
          console.log('dataSource tras filtrar por proyecto', this.dataSource);
        }
      );
  }
```

> Considerar el modelo de datos ya que la desestructuracion puede dar
> con find() resultados no deseados al asignar undefined a una propiedad

En el ejemplo trate de repetir la logica de la pregunta con dos arrays de objetos  modificando una propiedad del array  peces de acuerdo a si se cumple una condicion relacionada con el otro array pajaros pero si el primer array peces cuenta con varios objetos  el resultado no sera el deseado  si contara solo con uno que cumpliera la condicion si se obtendria lo deseado

```js
interface Bird {
    name:string;
    plumas:string | undefined
  }
  
  interface Fish {
     name:string
     aletas: string | undefined
  
  }
  const peces:Fish[]=[{name:'pedro',aletas:'rojas'},{name:'pepito',aletas:'rojas'}]
  const pajaros:Bird[]=[{name:'pep',plumas:'amarillas'},{name:'pepito',plumas:'amarillas'}]
  function mapear ({ peces, pajaros }: { peces: Fish[]; pajaros: Bird[] }):(Bird|Fish)[]{
  return peces.map(pe=>(
                  {
                   ...pe,
                   aletas: pajaros.find(pa =>
                   { return pa.name === pe.name}
                    )?.plumas
                  } 
                     ) as unknown as Bird
                     )
  }
console.log(mapear({ peces, pajaros }))
```

```js
// muestra
{ name: 'pedro', aletas: undefined },  
 
 { name: 'pepito', aletas: 'amarillas' }
```

> La alertas  son adecuadas pues puede aignarse a una propiedad un valor
> undefined  pese a que  nosotros le estamos diciendo que no  lo haremos
> Fijate en el ejemplo con los peces y pajaros si peces tiene a un solo
> miembro el cual ademas tiene el mismo nombre que un pajaro se
> modificara el color de la aleta del pez por el color de la pluma del
> pajaro que tiene el mismo nombre y listo! Pero si peces tiene mas de
> un objeto daremos el valor undefined para los que no tienen el mismo
> nombre.

Para evitar esto  agrego una funcion que maneje al objeto cuando sea undefined

```js
interface Bird {
  name: string;
  plumas: string
}

interface Fish {
  name: string
  aletas: string

}

const peces: Fish[] = [{ name: 'maria', aletas: 'naranjas' }, { name: 'pedro', aletas: 'rojas' }, { name: 'pepito', aletas: 'rojas' }]
const pajaros: Bird[] = [{ name: 'pep', plumas: 'amarillas' }, { name: 'pepito', plumas: 'amarillas' }]
function mapear({ peces, pajaros }: { peces: Fish[]; pajaros: Bird[] }): (Bird | Fish)[] {
  return peces.map(pe => (
    {
      ...pe,
      aletas: encontrarColor(pe, pajaros)

    }
  ) as unknown as Bird
  )
}
console.log(mapear({ peces, pajaros }))

function encontrarColor(pe: Fish, pajaros: Bird[]): string {
  let encontrado = pajaros.find(pa =>
    pa.name === pe.name
  )
  let u = (encontrado !== undefined) ? encontrado.plumas : pe.aletas;
  return u

}
```

> En el resultado que muestra se verfifica que no modificamos ninguna
> propiedad por un valor undefined El que nos indique el compilador un
> posible objeto undefined es de mucha utilidad para tomar los recaudos
> para que esto no ocurra

```js
 npx ts-node tesy.ts
[
  { name: 'maria', aletas: 'naranjas' },
  { name: 'pedro', aletas: 'rojas' },
  { name: 'pepito', aletas: 'amarillas' }
]
```

> tambien podes encadenar por ejemplo de esta forma

`find(p=>p.id==aval?.proyectoId)?.clienteNombre` y hay tambien muchas mas formas para que no se queje

> pero hay que tener recaudos como mencione antes para   manejar
> un posible undefined pues nos alerta que  si puede ocurrir de acuerdo a nuestro codigo

[How to solve TypeScript possibly undefined value](https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-solve-typescript-possibly-undefined-value)

Comment: en mi proyecto local añadiendo lo que comentas me sigue marcando error en los métodos find, pero solo cuando añado this.ofertas$ al final, es lo curioso con las otras 6 propiedades mapeadas no se queja

Comment: En realidad la alerta es adecuada pues puede aignarse a una propiedad un valor undefined fijate en el ejemplo con los peces y pajaros si peces tiene a un solo miembro el cual ademas tiene el mismo nombre que un pajaro se modificara el color de la aleta del pez por el color de la pluma del pajaro que tiene el mismo nombre y listo! pero si peces tiene mas de un objeto daremos el valor undefined para los que no tienen el mismo nombre.Para evitar estola  agrego una funcion que maneje al objeto cuando sea undefined te la agrego a la respuesta